# What is the FM-N mode?

Tags: modes, fm

I'm reading the Icom IC-51E PLUS2 manual and it says it supports the following modes:

- AM
- FM
- FM-N
- DV

What is FM-N? I'm new to amateur radio and never heard of it before. It's not listed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_amateur_radio_modes) either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FM-N stands for FM narrow band.This corresponds to a 2.5 kHz deviation. FM corresponds to a 5 kHz deviation. Most repeaters are still 5 kHz although with spectrum crowding, we will see more 2.5 kHz repeaters to allow more repeaters to be located in the same frequency allocation. This mirrors what is happening in the commercial 2 way market.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Glenn. Is it normally used in simplex mode? I was listening yesterday to a conversation and switching between FM and FM-N made no difference. Does it mean they were using FM-N?

Comment: If it makes no difference in listening that is great; however, transmitting 2.5 KHz deviation might sound quieter to others on a channel that is nominally 5 KHz.